# Overloaded constructors

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

After reading overloaded constructors from a book, i tired the following code:

```
public class Employee {

    String name;
    int idNumber;

    public Employee(){
        this("JJ", 0);
        System.out.println(name +" "+ idNumber);
    }

    public Employee(String name, int num){

        this.name = name;
        idNumber = num;
        System.out.println(name +" 2nd "+ idNumber);
    }
}


public class Object1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
JJ 2nd 0

JJ 0
```

I am really confused. Why "JJ 2nd 0" printed out first then "JJ 0"?? I created an employee object emp and did not pass any args in the parameter, isn't suppose to call the first constructor first?

Comment: Perhaps if people used [debuggers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) a lot more, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Qix Thanks. Never heard of debugger before but I did google it and i m going to learn how to use it now.

Comment: I just realized, you've asked a number of questions, but haven't accepted any answers yet. It might be a good idea to accept some, if they were truly helpful, both as a way of saying "thank you", and to indicate to future users who look at the question which answer best answered the question.

Comment: @PaulRichter I am new to the forum so not sure how it works. I thought upvote is the way to show the appreciation. I will accept all the answers right now. How to accept answers?

Comment: @taimeili123 Upvoting is definitely good, but its more to show that the answer was good, or useful. Looks like you already discovered the green "accept" checkmark next to the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Employee();` is invoking

```
public Employee(){
    this("JJ", 0);
    System.out.println(name +" "+ idNumber);
}
```

In this constructor

`this("JJ", 0);`

is invoking

`public Employee(String name, int num)`

constructor, which ends with call

`System.out.println(name +" 2nd "+ idNumber);`.

which is responsible for printing

> JJ 2nd 0

When `this("JJ", 0);` will finish  `System.out.println(name +" "+ idNumber);` will be invoked and you should see another line

> JJ 0

Answer (score 4):

When you wrote:

```
... new Employee();
```

You end up calling the default (no-argument) constructor. The **first** line of code in that constructor is:

```
this("JJ", 0);
```

Which calls the 2-parameter constructor, in which you write

```
System.out.println(name +" 2nd "+ idNumber);
```

This is the first of the two output statements your program encounters, and thus is the first thing you see in the console.

After that output statement, the program returns to the default no-argument constructor, and proceeds to execute your other output statement

```
System.out.println(name +" "+ idNumber);
```

Which is the "second" output statement you see.

If you step through your code with a debugger, go line by line, you will see exactly how the program is executing, and should demonstrate what I am referring to.

Answer (score 2):

The no-argument constructor is calling the other constructor with arguments with the following line:

```
this("JJ", 0);
```

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

It do call the first constructor first, but the first line in it, is a call to the second constructor. When you create the `Employee` object from the `main` method, you call the constructor `Employee()`, with no arguments (the first one). That constructor first calls the second constructor, which prints `JJ 2nd 0`, and then, the first constructor prints the line `JJ 0`. This is how it gets executed:

1. When the `main` method is being called, the first constructor, `new Employee()`, is called.
2. The constructor calls the second constructor.
3. The second constructor prints `JJ 2nd 0`, and then it's done.
4. The first constructor continues with the next line, which is `System.out.println(name +" "+ idNumber);`, and prints `JJ 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read about the this keyword for that , Just for starters its like and object of the class your'e using,

```
                       See in the first constructor this("JJ","0") means that a constructor having two arguments is being invoked so the first line redirects the control into the second constructor that's is why the other line is printed first.
```