# Why we have more than one class constructors in a class and what its their possible use?

Tags: java, android

By reading an example here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

it is defining a class with

Todo.java

```
package info.androidhive.sqlite.model;

public class Todo {

int id;
String note;
int status;
String created_at;

// constructors
public Todo() {
}

public Todo(String note, int status) {
    this.note = note;
    this.status = status;
}

public Todo(int id, String note, int status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.note = note;
    this.status = status;
}
```

why is that ? the last constructor isnt enough?

Comment: you have to understand overloading concept in java.http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/  and http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-is-constructor-overloading-in-java.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloaded constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610274/overloaded-constructors)

Comment: One is for creating an object with the id field set, the other not. Pretty self evident, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you Stallion

Comment: if i want two different use case, in first i want to get object with id and note and second one is for id note and status, than what should i do?

Comment: By the way: This example is not really good because it shows an Object that can be created with one field "undefined". While this _may_ not have an effect in the specific system it is generally not a good idea. In this case there should be one specific value that has the meaning of "id unknown" and that be set in the ctor without id. Not to speak about the parameterless ctor ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can notice there is three constructors but with three different parameters.

First constructor:

```
public Todo()
```

Second constructor:

```
public Todo(String note, int status)
```

Third constructor:

```
public Todo(int id, String note, int status)
```

The reason behind multiple constructors is how the objects of Todo class will be initialized.

To visualize what im saying take this example: Todo object could be initialize with one of the these three ways:

```
//fist method 
Todo todoObject = new Todo();

//second method with a status of 0
Todo todoObject = new Todo("write note here", 0);

//third method whith id:1152 and status:0
Todo todoObject = new Todo(1552,"write note here", 0);
```